# Name & value - Go vs Python

Tags: python, go

In python, with below code,

```
x = 3
x='str'
```

allows `x` to first point to `int` type object and then to `str` type object, because python is **dynamic typed**. `type(x)` gives type of value(`3` or `str`) **but not** type of name `x`.

In-fact, `x` does not store value `3` but point to `int` type object whose value is `3`

---

In GO language, with below syntax,

```
func main() {
        y := 2
        fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(y)) // gives 'int'
        y = "str" // Compile time error, because GO is static typed 
}
```

**Question:**

Is `int`, the type of name `y` or the type of value `2`?

Comment: In my mind, *values* have types. Not names. But in statically typed languages, a given name can only refer to values of the type it was declared to refer to. It cannot change. That is why they are *statically* typed. Just think about it as a promise to the compiler: "in this scope, `x` will always refer to a value of type `int`"

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga In Go and other statically typed languages, both variables and values have types, and the declared type of the variable must match the type of the value that it holds.

Comment: @DYZ yeah, I suppose that is correct. Values and Names are both said to be "typed". In any event, it seems like a subtle semantic difference with no concrete difference.

Comment: Go does not have the notion of "name" like python does. Go has the concept of a "variable". `x` is a variable. Variables have types and values. The type of variable `x` is `int` and the value is `3`. No names involved. The concept "variable" is closely related to the idea of "has a certain, fixed memory address and fixed memory layout".

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga x:=3 syntax in GO leads to a confusion, because that syntax looks similar to python, despite GO compiler does type inference to find the type of x at compile time. Not sure, why static typed languages provide such syntax?

Comment: @Volker I would have a small quibble: Go does implicitly have a concept of "names" since it does have classic "variables". A variable as such consists of an identifier (a name) and an associated storage location (chunk of organized memory). In Python, it is a better mental model to just think of variables as just names, with no associated storage location. But if you come from statically typed languages closer to the metal like C, one might think in terms of classic variables if you limit variables in Python to Py_Object* pointer  types (for CPython... implementation detail yadda yadda).

Comment: @overexchange Most consider it a feature, I would say. I like type inference. It is liberating to be able to use powerful type systems in languages like Haskell and Scala without so much boilerplate! As for Go, I've only dabbled, but I enjoy it. It is gives you the speed of a statically typed, compiled language like Java or C++ but it feels almost like writing Python, despite the curly braces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python variables are bound to instances of classes that are assigned to them dynamically over the course of the program. Therefore, and especially with mutable objects, they are merely pointers who contain information about their data location and the type of the data they point to. That's why, upon assigning a new value, you are creating a new instance (which is your main interest) and bind the variable name to it, so the type is related to the *value*, not the variable itself.

```
>>> x = 3; id(x)
1996006560
>>> x = 'str'; id(x)
1732654458784
```

---

Go variables on the other hand, are serving (when not pointers) as stronghold memory locations, as the language is compiled and the variables get a constant "job" to keep a certain type of information (which could be a pointer as well). Therefore, a variable would almost certainly maintain his memory along the program, will have constant datatype properties, and, you could say the variable itself is of a certain type (and not of a semi-pointer type).

```
package main
import . "fmt"
func main () {
    x := "str"; Println(&x)         // 0xc04203a1c0
    x = "Hello world!"; Println(&x) // 0xc04203a1c0
}
```